# Unable to delete the row, upon clicking the delete button in laravel/mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, laravel

I have been working on an example with scratch given in:"https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart". I am unable to delete the row upon clicking the delete button!

Web/Route.php

```
Route::get('/', 'TaskDisplayController@taskdisplay');

Route::post('/taskdisplay', function () {
    return view('/taskdisplay');
});
Route::get('/taskdisplay', function () {
    return view('/taskdisplay');
});

Route::post('/tasklistdisplay', 'TaskDisplayController@tasklistdisplay');
Route::get('/tasklistdisplay', 'TaskDisplayController@tasklistdisplay');

Route::post('/TaskDisplay', 'TaskDisplayController@taskdisplay');
Route::get('/TaskDisplay', 'TaskDisplayController@taskdisplay');

Route::delete('/tasklistdisplay/{id}', function ($id) {
    DB::table('tasktable')->findOrFail($id)->delete();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

TaskDisplayController.php

```
class TaskDisplayController extends BaseController
{
    public function taskdisplay()
    {
        $task_ = DB::table('tasktable')->select('task','taskid','id')->get();
        return view('taskdisplay',['task'=> $task_]);
    }

    public function tasklistdisplay(Request $req)
    {
        $task_=$req->input('taskfield');
        if(DB::insert('insert into tasktable (id, task) values (1, ?)',[$task_]))
        {
            return redirect('/TaskDisplay');
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Login failed; Wrong data entered";
        }
    }
}
```

taskdisplay.blade.php

```
<table>
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Task ID</th>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Task</th>
        <th>Options</th>             
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        @foreach($task as  $tsk)
            <td>{{$tsk->taskid }}</td>
            <td>{{$tsk->id }}</td>
            <td>{{$tsk->task }}</td>
            <td>
            <form action="/task/{{ $tsk->id }}" method="post" >
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
                <button>Delete Task</button>
            </form>
            </td>
            </tr>
            @endforeach
<input type="hidden" value={{csrf_token()}} name=_token>
</tbody>        
</table>
```

Expect it to work like :https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/quickstart
But upon clicking the delete button 404 page not found is shown

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust the action route as shown below:

```
action="/tasklistdisplay/{{ $tsk->id }}"
```

`findOrFail` is an eloquent function not `Query Builder`. So it should be:

```php
DB::table('tasktable')->whereId($id)->delete();
```

Comment: Working great, the simplest and the best answer :)

Comment: @SYEDSHEHROZSOHAIL So it should be the accepted answer, no?

Comment: If I want to delete on the basis of taskid instead of id what changes should I do?

Comment: If you're using any other column instead of `id`, you can do it `DB::table('tasktable')->where('taskid', $taskId)->delete();` I hope I got your question correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the route you're meant to go to is `tasklistdisplay` (as it's the only `delete` route you've shown), however, in your form you've set the action to be `"/task/{{ $tsk->id }}"`.

Try changing the action to:

```
action="/tasklistdisplay/{{ $tsk->id }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

please fix your post url in form :
your route is :

```
Route::delete('/tasklistdisplay/{id}'
```

but your form is :

```
 <form action="/task/{{ $tsk->id }}" method="post" >
```

it should be :

```
<form action="/tasklistdisplay/{{ $tsk->id }}" method="post" >
```

Answer (score 0):

The click going to 404 because there isn't the DELETE route in your web/route.php.

The delete route that you are calling is defined in the `action` attribute in `form` tag.

This route

```
Route::delete('/tasklistdisplay/{id}', function ($id) {
    DB::table('tasktable')->findOrFail($id)->delete();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

should be

```
Route::delete('/task/{id}', function ($id) {
    DB::table('tasktable')->findOrFail($id)->delete();
    return redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: If I want to delete on the basis of taskid instead of id what changes should I do?

Answer (score 0):

`DB::table('tasktable')->delete(1)` 
This will Help